# New to Sphinx in PyCharm

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, python-sphinx

I am using PyCharm as my IDE to create my python application. As I understand it has a build in documentation feature based on two different programs where one of them is Sphinx.

I am trying to set up my folders but I find that either the documentation in how this is done is lacking or there is something basic I've missed.

My project folder structure is the following

```
app/ - for my main application
plugins/plugin_names/version_id/ - Folder for plugins to main application can use
sphinx/doc/ - setup folder for sphinx generated by quick start.
```

Now when I try to run this through PyCarm. Setting up a run configuration pointing it input to **spinx/doc/source** and output to **sphinx/doc/build**.

when I execute this configuration I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.3\helpers\rest_runners\sphinx_runner.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sphinx import cmdline
  File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\sphinx\cmdline.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sphinx.application import Sphinx
  File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\sphinx\application.py", line 37, in <module>
    from sphinx.builders import BUILTIN_BUILDERS
  File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\sphinx\builders\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from sphinx.util import i18n, path_stabilize
  File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\sphinx\util\i18n.py", line 15, in <module>
    from babel.messages.pofile import read_po
  File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\babel\messages\__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from babel.messages.catalog import *
  File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\babel\messages\catalog.py", line 23, in <module>
    from babel.dates import format_datetime
  File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\babel\dates.py", line 28, in <module>
    from babel.util import UTC, LOCALTZ
  File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\babel\util.py", line 278, in <module>
    from babel import localtime
  File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\babel\localtime\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from babel.localtime._win32 import _get_localzone
  File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\babel\localtime\_win32.py", line 18, in <module>
    tz_names = get_global('windows_zone_mapping')
  File "C:\python34\lib\site-packages\babel\core.py", line 58, in get_global
    _global_data = pickle.load(fileobj)
TypeError: an integer is required (got type str)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 4.5.3\helpers\rest_runners\sphinx_runner.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise NameError("Cannot find sphinx in selected interpreter.")
NameError: Cannot find sphinx in selected interpreter.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I do not know why it has to be so complicated all i want is a program to take an input file and generate and output html.

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason was due to bable version 2.0. downgrading to bable version 1.3 solved the problem