# PyCharm: Cannot find Sphinx in selected interpreter

Tags: django, pycharm, python-sphinx

I am trying to create documentation using Sphinx in PyCharm and it does not work. I already tried using the terminal command `make html` and it seems to work just fine. When I try to run Sphinx task in PyCharm it raises this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/rest_runners/sphinx_runner.py", line 5, in <module>
    from sphinx import cmdline
  File "/Users/wtekimam/PycharmProjects/doctor/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sphinx/cmdline.py", line 24, in <module>
    from sphinx.application import Sphinx
  File "/Users/wtekimam/PycharmProjects/doctor/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 33, in <module>
    from sphinx.environment import BuildEnvironment
  File "/Users/wtekimam/PycharmProjects/doctor/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sphinx/environment/__init__.py", line 45, in <module>
    from sphinx.util.websupport import is_commentable
  File "/Users/wtekimam/PycharmProjects/doctor/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sphinx/util/websupport.py", line 11, in <module>
    from sphinxcontrib.websupport.utils import is_commentable  # NOQA
  File "/Users/wtekimam/PycharmProjects/doctor/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sphinxcontrib/websupport/__init__.py", line 13, in <module>
    __import__('pkg_resources').declare_namespace(__name__)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 961, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 950, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 646, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 616, in _load_backward_compatible
  File "/Users/wtekimam/PycharmProjects/doctor/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3017, in <module>
  File "/Users/wtekimam/PycharmProjects/doctor/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3003, in _call_aside
  File "/Users/wtekimam/PycharmProjects/doctor/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 3045, in _initialize_master_working_set
  File "/Users/wtekimam/PycharmProjects/doctor/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2577, in activate
  File "/Users/wtekimam/PycharmProjects/doctor/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2151, in declare_namespace
  File "/Users/wtekimam/PycharmProjects/doctor/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2091, in _handle_ns
  File "/Users/wtekimam/PycharmProjects/doctor/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools-28.8.0-py3.6.egg/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2120, in _rebuild_mod_path
AttributeError: '_NamespacePath' object has no attribute 'sort'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/rest_runners/sphinx_runner.py", line 7, in <module>
    raise NameError("Cannot find sphinx in selected interpreter.")
NameError: Cannot find sphinx in selected interpreter.
```

note: I use virtual environment and I already configure PyCharm to use the same virtual environment that I use to run `make html` in terminal

Answer (score 3):

There are two requirements:

1. Install Sphinx into your project's interpreter.
2. Create a run configuration for a Sphinx task with the appropriate settings as specified in [PyCharm's documentation](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/run-debug-configuration-sphinx-task.html).

   Here's a typical configuration with screenshot.

   - Command: html
   - Input: `path/to/reST/source/files`
   - Output: `path/to/reST/build/files`
   - Python Interpreter: Project Default (or whatever you select)
   - Working directory: `path/to/conf.py`

[image: Sphinx task run configuration]

Comment: I did that but it still doesn't work for me. i have installed Sphinx in the project's interpreter and used the same setting that you have in your screenshot

Comment: After creating that run configuration, how do you invoke it? Clicking the Run button with the task selected should work. The error message states "Cannot find sphinx in selected interpreter." so you either selected the wrong interpreter or it is in fact not installed. Check the installed packages for the interpreter via _PyCharm > Preferences > Project: name > Project Interpreter_.

Comment: Yes I did just that. I clicked the run button with the sphinx task selected. I checked the Project interpreter and it is installed. I also picked the right interpreter where the Sphinx is installed (I have actually tried all the available interpreter and it still doesn't work and it generates a shorter error if I picked the wrong interpreter). Anything I might've missed?

Comment: Based on [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32624461/new-to-sphinx-in-pycharm), I see the package `setuptools` in your virtual environment is in the error stack. I vaguely recall that older versions of `setuptools` had an issue with namespaces, so you can try to upgrade it, or if that fails, uninstall and reinstall the latest version. Let me know if that resolves the issue. Oh, yes, it seems to have come up a second time in this issue on GitHub: https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/4216

Answer (score -1):

The solution is to update all packages that are used in the interpreter.
In particular, **update the *setuptools* package**.

This worked for me, but I do not know why, I am sorry. None of the answers above helped.